# Hiding a button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Please help me to hide the button using jQuery or css.

```
    <div align="center">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
         </div>
        <button onclick="window.close();">Close</button> 
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

first give your button a id

```
<button id="btnclose" onclick="window.close();">Close</button>
```

then using jQuery

```
jQuery("#btnclose").hide();
```

hope this serves your purpose.

UPDATE -

```
jQuery('.popup-content').parent().last().hide();
```

check this fiddle - jsfiddle.net/jLkv4b2d

Comment: There's no need for an ID.

Comment: @Manb then,try this 
jQuery('button').hide();

Comment: If popup-content div contains buttons then it will affect on all buttons, How can be specific to a particular button

Comment: @Manb My answer doesn't select the particular button..?

Comment: @Manb jQuery('.popup-content').parent().last().hide();

there are several ways to refer a element.

check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jLkv4b2d/

Comment: @TJ No its not selecting

Comment: @Manb [It is](http://jsfiddle.net/jLkv4b2d/1/) [selecting](http://jsfiddle.net/jLkv4b2d/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Using css:

```
.popup-content+button{
 display:none;
}
```

---

jQuery:

```
$(".popup-content+button").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give that button some id and hide that button using jquery like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button id='btn'>Button<button>
```

**Jquery**:

$("#btn").hide();

**Jquery to hide the button when it is clicked:**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
```

Comment: How can i add the button dynamically in this case ?

Comment: What are you trying to say? I think what you are trying to do is to click the button and then hide that clicked button. for that I am editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    $(this).css('visibility:hidden;')
})
```

This code will remove any button when it is clicked, even if that button was added to the DOM after this handler was declared. The reason why I don't use `display:none;` is because elements with `display:none;` don't take up space in the document flow, so your other elements might rearrange themselves. Using `visibility:hidden;` will hide the element, but it will still take up space (which I think is what you want here).